# It is any way to add dynamic attribute to openldap user when it on group?

Tags: ldap, openldap, groups

I'm searching way to implement automatically add some attribute and value (identical for all) in search response for user, if user is member of group (memberof overlay is enabled).
For example:
User is `uid=test,ou=users,dc=test,dc=local`
It has operational attribute

```
memberOf : cn=testgroup,ou=groups,dc=test,dc=local
```

If I searching for `uid=test,ou=users,dc=test,dc=local`, I  need to get attribute/value `testattribute : testvalue` in result object attributes list.

I found that dynamic lists overlay can implement something similar. 
Does anybody know how to implement it?

Comment: Could you better explain your use case? Why doesn't the use of the `memberOf` attribute from `slapo-memberof` already work for what you're trying to do?

Comment: I'm integrating with Lenovo \ IBM Integrated Management Module, And in case of OpenLDAP integration it needs both Group Membershipment , and string attribute for access rules management. I'm trying to sumplify management and Add attribute for access rules management automaticly with group membershipment. 
As a workarround I extend my group with custom class with attribute fow acess right management. Situation is also explained here: [lenovo forum](https://forums.lenovo.com/t5/System-x-X6-M5-M4/System-X-IMM-LDAP-group-authentication-problem/td-p/3770828)

Comment: Take a look at `slapo-rwm` which is overlay that does rewrite and remapping.